# Android - shape on horizontal line

Tags: android, android-xml, android-shape

I have a `xml`, that in this `xml` I adding `Horizontal Line` between `TextViews`.
I add a `Shape` to separator but I can't see changes.

```
main_activity.xml :

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:text="HELLO"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/vVerticalLine"
    android:background="@drawable/horizontal_shape"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_height="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:text="HELLO"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

and my `horizontal_shape.xml` :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

    <stroke
        android:color="#000000" />

</shape>
```

For example I need :

[image]

Comment: background of main_activity.xml is white .

Comment: use <solid> not stroke.

Comment: @ Harry . Your help is true . Response question for vote. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
    <size
        android:height="6dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#daa520" />

</shape>
```

Comment: This worked for me, while no other solutions on SO were helping. Thanks!