# Underline within a Textview in android studio XML

Tags: android, textview

I want to put a horizontal line within a textview in android studio. I want to create a textview layout like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get `TextView` with a line .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Device"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_textview"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

- create linear layout with `match_parent` width
- set orientation vertical
- put text view child with `wrap_content` width
- put view with 0dp width and `weight = 1`

  ```
  <View 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="1dp"       
      android:background="#000"
      android:gravity="bottom" />
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Do it Programitically Like..

(Use _ for Making a Line)

```
yourTextView.setText("Device_________________________");
yourTextView.setTextColor("Your Color Here");
```

and In XML file Set

> Android:width = "MatchParent".

for your Text View.

Do this only if you are creating static layout.

Answer (score 0):

Draw custom drawable and set to `drawableEnd` to `textview`
Drawable can something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29531952/7413139)..
and do not forgot to set `textview` width `match parent`